# strchr for multiple characters?

Tags: c++

How can I check if two char arrays have any characters in common ? Obviously strchr won't work in this case because it can only search for one character but I used it to give you an idea about what I want to do.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
    char text[]="example text",
         find_this[]={'p','t','e','\0'};
    if (strchr(text,find_this))
        cout<<"Found!";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hint: how would you do it with a piece of paper and a pencil?

Comment: BTW: in stead of `find_this[]={'p','t','e','\0'}` you can simply write `find_this[]="pte"`

Comment: @Jabberwocky I'd just circle the matching characters!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit :-) come on..

Comment: I think two for statements could do the job here. I mean just compare every character in order and see if it matches . However if anyone has a more efficient idea please tell me :)

Comment: Hint 2: Your first idea with `strchr` is not entirely wrong. Be aware that the second parameter of `strchr` is not a `char*` but a `char`. Algorithm: for each character in `find_this` : call `strchr(text, character)`.

Comment: @VladaMisici _just compare every character in order and see if it matches_: yes, this is more or less what you need to do. Write this program (3-4 lines of code) and test it. Worry about optimisation only once it works. BTW are you asking for C or for C++?

Comment: @Jabberwocky I'm asking for C++. By the way , thank you for the tips !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    char text[]      = "example text";
    char find_this[] = "pte";

    auto it = std::find_first_of(
        std::begin(text), std::end(text),
        std::begin(find_this), std::end(find_this)-1
    );

    if (it != std::end(text))
       std::cout << "Found!";
}
```

#### [(live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c8b1c3567832012e))

Notice that I reduce the `find_this` range by one, to discount its null terminator (as that's assuredly present in the input range!). If I were clever I'd just use a range that discounts the null terminator in both cases. You can do that yourself.